# What is wrong with the following jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, toggle

The following jQuery does nothing.
Did I miss a comma or something?

```
<script>
$(".link<? echo $counter; ?>").click(function () {
    $('.sub').toggle(function () {
        $(".sub<? echo $counter; ?>").animate({
            height: ($(this).parent().height() * <? echo(count($$vari)); ?> ) + 20
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $(".sub<? echo $counter; ?>").animate({
            height: 0
        }, 1000);
    });
});    
</script>
```

The console does not trow any error's and when I change the code to

```
<script>
$(".link<? echo $counter; ?>").click(function() {
$(".sub<? echo $counter; ?>").animate({
height: ($(this).parent().height() * <? echo (count($$vari)); ?>) + 20
}, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

The script works (except for the toggle ofcource)

Comment: What's the console error and what is mean for $$vari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toggle()` function used that way has been removed in jQuery 1.9, and now only shows and hides elements. What the PHP outputs is impossible for us to know, but you normally should'nt use shorttags ?

Also note that you are binding a click inside a click, and everytime the `.link*` elements are clicked, a new event handler is bound to the `.sub` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Before you click on the link, use developer tools on your browser and make sure that the listener has actually been added on the control. Also, what do you mean by "does nothing"? What is your expectation?